# Create test run with state property in Azure DevOps .NET SDK

Tags: c#, .net, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm using the Azure DevOps .NET SDK (v16.530.0-preview) and when I try to create a test run using `CreateTestRunAsync` (in `TestManagementHttpClient`) and use the `RunCreateModel` object as a parameter, it looks like the `RunCreateModel`'s `State` property is read-only. The docs also confirm this.

```
TestApi.RunCreateModel run = new TestApi.RunCreateModel
{
     Name = testRun.Name
     //State = testRun.State (is read-only)
};
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.teamfoundation.testmanagement.webapi.runcreatemodel.state?view=azure-devops-dotnet-preview#Microsoft_TeamFoundation_TestManagement_WebApi_RunCreateModel_State

But the weirdness is that when creating the run, the UI shows `In Progress` then it shows the test run running for {x hours, minutes, sec}.

Is there a way I can avoid this and set the state as `NotStarted`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the state in the constructor:

```
var testRun = new RunCreateModel(name: "API Test Run", state: "NotStarted");
var results = testApi.CreateTestAsync(testRun, "Project").Result;
```

I succeeded to create a test run with "Not Started" state with the above code.

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick! Must have just been the way I was calling the RunCreateModel. Thanks for your help!